# Java live chat opensource

Tags: java, chat, live

Does anybody know any Java live chat opensource? I want to embed into the application.
Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try using this one http://sourceforge.net/projects/llamachat I hope it's what you're looking for